# How do I set CXXFLAGS in the makefile to compile with gcc?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, icc

I am trying to install ALAMODE (https://alamode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on ubuntu 16.04. T

he default CXXFLAGS in the makefiles are set for icpc (CXX = icpc). However, I want to set them for gcc. How can I do that?

Here are the default CXXFLAGS:

```
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -xHOST -qopenmp -std=c++11
```

Comment: `CXX=gcc CXXFLAGS="-O2 -std=c++11" make` should work ([link to makefile](https://alamode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id2))

Comment: Paste the relevant part of the Makefile into your question. I had to hunt for it....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Now I am getting this error:
 cc1plus: error: argument to ‘-O’ should be a non-negative integer, ‘g’, ‘s’ or ‘fast’

Comment: @selbie, Thank you for your suggestion. I have added that part in the question.

Comment: Make sure that is `-O2` (dash Oh two) NOT (dash Zero two)

Comment: Are you asking how to set values, or what the values ought to be?

Comment: My suspicion is that the problem is `-xHOST`.  I don't know what you hope that option will do, but as far as I can see it's not valid. `-x` takes a language target: see this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I set it as  `-O2`, then I got this error.

Comment: @Beta, I am trying to understand how can I set the values. Also, as I am new in this area, it will be a great help if you can provide me the values. Thanks.

Comment: You can set the values as @DavidC.Rankin showed (although I would put `make` at the beginning of the command, not the end). I do not know what the values ought to be for your case.